# Function definition in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I was trying to define and run a simple function in a class.

Can anybody please tell me what's wrong in my code:

```
class A :
    def m1(name,age,address) :
        print('Name -->',name)
        print('Age -->',age)
        print('Address -->',address)


>>> a = A()
>>> a.m1('X',12,'XXXX')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#22>", line 1, in <module>
    a.m1('X',12,'XXXX')
```

I am getting below error 
**TypeError: m1() takes exactly 3 positional arguments (4 given)**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Instance methods take instance as first argument:

```
class A :
    def m1(self, name,age,address) :
        print('Name -->',name)
        print('Age -->',age)
        print('Address -->',address)
```

You can also use [@staticmethod decorator](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod) to create static function:

```
class A :
    @staticmethod
    def m1(name,age,address) :
        print('Name -->',name)
        print('Age -->',age)
        print('Address -->',address)
```

Answer (score 4):

By convention, methods in a class instance receive an object reference as the 1st argument, named `self`.

```
>>> class A:
...     def m1(self,name,age,address):
...         print('Name -->',name)
...         print('Age -->',age)
...         print('Address -->',address)
...         
>>> a=A()
>>> a.m1('X',12,'XXXX')
('Name -->', 'X')
('Age -->', 12)
('Address -->', 'XXXX')
>>>
```

Comment: that's not a class method, that's instance method.

Answer (score 4):

The first parameter is always the object itself.

```
class A :
    def m1(self, name,age,address) :
        print('Name -->',name)
        print('Age -->',age)
        print('Address -->',address)
```